# Flask - how to route app to ip address instead of localhost

Tags: python, flask

I am very new to Flask. I have built a Flask application and I am hosting it on a server. Below is the code for the flask application

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./Predicted.csv")
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/submit", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit_table():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit'] == 'Get Started!':
            html_string = df.to_html()
            return render_template('submit.html', q1=html_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=5050, threaded=True)
```

I need the app to be visible to the internal organisation only. The server name is 10.143.284.249 
When I go to the following link, it works  http://10.143.284.249:5050/. However, when I click on the "Get Started!" button, it redirects to http://localhost:5000/submit and when I changed it to  http://10.143.284.249:5050/submit I get an internal service error.

I have 2 questions,

1) How can I change my code so that it redirects to the address of the server and not localhost:5000 but 10.143.284.249:5050

2) What is causing the internal service error, because when I ran it locally, it was working.

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to let an application run the webserver on it's own. I would advise you to use nginx to route it or apache using proxypass.  In any case, could you provide some tracebacks?

Comment: What's in `index.html`? It's hard to say why it redirects to localhost without it.

Comment: `index.html` is the main web sit landing page

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error is probably caused by `submit_table()` not returning anything for `GET`. If you plan on supporting `GET` and `POST`, your function should return something to the browser in both cases.

You haven't included your `index.html`, so I can't say for sure if clicking on Get Started would use `POST`. But once you manually browse to http://10.143.284.249:5050/submit, that'd definitely be using `GET` and your function doesn't handle that.